# Add custom folders to classpath in bazel java tests

Tags: java, maven, bazel

I'm trying to migrate a large codebase from maven to bazel and I've found that some of the tests write to `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` and the production code reads it as resources on the classpath. This is because maven surefire/failsafe run by default from the module directory and add `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` to the classpath.
For me to migrate this large codebase the only reasonable solution is to create target, target/classes and target/test-classes folders and add the last two to the classpath of the tests.
Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another line of approach. Instead of generating a test suite, create a custom javaagent and a custom class loader. Use `jvm_flags` to setup and configure it.

The javaagent has a premain method. This sounds like a natural place to do things that happen before the regular main method, even if they don't have anything to do with class instrumentation, debugging, coverage gathering, or any other usual uses of javaagents.

The custom javaagent reads system property `extra.dirs` and creates directories specified there. It then reads property `extra.link.path` and creates the symbolic links as specified there, so I can place resources where the tests expect them, without having to copy them.

Classloader is needed so that we can amend the classpath at runtime without hacks. Great advantage is that this solution works on Java 10.

The custom classloader reads system property `extra.class.path` and (in effect) prepends it before what is in `java.class.path`.

Doing things this way means that standard bazel rules can be used.

## BUILD

```
runtime_classgen_dirs = ":".join([
            "target/classes",
            "target/test-classes",
])
java_test(
    ...,
    jvm_flags = [
        # agent
        "-javaagent:$(location //tools:test-agent_deploy.jar)",
        "-Dextra.dirs=" + runtime_classgen_dirs,
        # classloader
        "-Djava.system.class.loader=ResourceJavaAgent",
        "-Dextra.class.path=" + runtime_classgen_dirs,
    ],
    ,,,,
    deps = [
        # not runtime_deps, cause https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1566
        "//tools:test-agent_deploy.jartest-agent_deploy.jar"
    ],
    ...,
)
```

## tools/BUILD

```
java_binary(
    name = "test-agent",
    testonly = True,
    srcs = ["ResourceJavaAgent.java"],
    deploy_manifest_lines = ["Premain-Class: ResourceJavaAgent"],
    main_class = "ResourceJavaAgent",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

## tools/ResourceJavaAgent.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime
public class ResourceJavaAgent extends URLClassLoader {
    private final ClassLoader parent;

    public ResourceJavaAgent(ClassLoader parent) throws MalformedURLException {
        super(buildClassPath(), null);
        this.parent = parent; // I need the parent as backup for SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        System.out.println("initializing url classloader");
    }

    private static URL[] buildClassPath() throws MalformedURLException {
        final String JAVA_CLASS_PATH = "java.class.path";
        final String EXTRA_CLASS_PATH = "extra.class.path";
        List<String> paths = new LinkedList<>();
        paths.addAll(Arrays.asList(System.getProperty(EXTRA_CLASS_PATH, "").split(File.pathSeparator)));
        paths.addAll(Arrays.asList(System.getProperty(JAVA_CLASS_PATH, "").split(File.pathSeparator)));
        URL[] urls = new URL[paths.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            urls[i] = Paths.get(paths.get(i)).toUri().toURL(); // important only for resource url, really: this url must be absolute, to pass getClass().getResource("/users.properties").toURI()) with uri that isOpaque == false.
//            System.out.println(urls[i]);
        }
        // this is for spawnVM functionality in tests
        System.setProperty(JAVA_CLASS_PATH, System.getProperty(EXTRA_CLASS_PATH, "") + File.pathSeparator + System.getProperty(JAVA_CLASS_PATH));
        return urls;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String s) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            return super.loadClass(s);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return parent.loadClass(s);  // we search parent second, not first, as the default URLClassLoader would
        }
    }

    private static void createRequestedDirs() {
        for (String path : System.getProperty("extra.dirs", "").split(File.pathSeparator)) {
            new File(path).mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private static void createRequestedLinks() {
        String linkPaths = System.getProperty("extra.link.path", null);
        if (linkPaths == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (String linkPath : linkPaths.split(",")) {
            String[] fromTo = linkPath.split(":");
            Path from = Paths.get(fromTo[0]);
            Path to = Paths.get(fromTo[1]);
            try {
                Files.createSymbolicLink(from.toAbsolutePath(), to.toAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to create link " + linkPath, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws Exception {
        createRequestedDirs();
        createRequestedLinks();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I unfortunately needed to put this aside for some time but am now getting back to this and trying out your solution. Do you search the parent second to give the extra classpath priority? If I don't care about the priority can I remove this override and pass the parent to the super constructor?

Comment: I guess so. I put this aside too in the meantime ;) Looking at the thing now, I figure this is for priority, and it probably has to do something with `this.parent = parent; // I need the parent as backup for SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");` but I am not sure what/why anymore. It might be best to build this up again, progressively adding more and more things as they are identified as needed... Having a small self-testsuite so that it is not necessary to rerun all project tests after changes might help too, if this is serious project.

Comment: Anyways, my project is at https://github.com/jdanekrh/activemq-artemis/tree/bazel and I also used custom Maven plugin to scan and write out dependencies. It is the maven dependency:tree plugin in essence, I just added printing it out in Bazel format. I don't remember why the tool Bazel doc recommended did not work for me... https://github.com/jdanekrh/migration-tooling-plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you could tell the tests where to write these files (in case `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` are hardcoded), and then turn the test run into a `genrule`, then you can specify the genrule's outputs as `data` for the production binary's `*_binary` rule.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the first part, creating the directories. I still don't know how to add the latter two to classpath.

Starting from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/bazlets/+/master/tools/junit.bzl, I modified it to read

```
_OUTPUT = """import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import java.io.File;
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({%s})
public class %s {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
      new File("./target").mkdir();
    }
}
"""
_PREFIXES = ("org", "com", "edu")
# ...
```

I added the `@BeforeClass setUp method`.

I stored this as `junit.bzl` into `third_party` directory in my project.

Then in a `BUILD file`,

```
load("//third_party:junit.bzl", "junit_tests")

junit_tests(
    name = "my_bundled_test",
    srcs = glob(["src/test/java/**/*.java"]),
    data = glob(["src/test/resources/**"]),
resources = glob(["src/test/resources/**"]),
tags = [
    # ...
],
    runtime_deps = [
        # ...
    ],
],
    deps = [
        # ...
    ],
)
```

Now the test itself is wrapped with a setUp method which will create a directory for me. I am not deleting them afterwards, which is probably a sound idea to do.

The reason I need test resources in a directory (as opposed to in a jar file, which bazel gives by default) is that my test passes the URI to `new FileInputStream(new File(uri))`. If the file resides in a JAR, the URI will be `file:/path/to/my.jar!/my.file` and the rest of the test cannot work with such URI.

Comment: have you ever managed to solve that? I"m facing the same issue. Current unit test runs rely on resources being on disk, not in a jar (and the data attribute puts it at the wrong location)

Comment: I did solve it by writing a custom classloader and javaagent, as described here in my other answer: "Another line of approach. ...." I was able to make the tests run in Bazel without having to touch the test sources, so I could have Bazel and Maven builds each in a working state.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Will look at your recommended solution. If I could only convince bazel to not run my test code from within a jar file, but I wasn't able to find any option to do that

Comment: Yeah. In the Maven world, building a test-jar is something exceptional, that you do rarely (when I want to reuse test code between maven modules). In Bazel, all test code ends up in jars. If you are able to find alternative solution than what I end up doing, I'd like to hear it.